# Can't figure out Unirest persistent login

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

I'm trying to log in persistently to a site using the Unirest HTTP Library for NodeJs, but after posting login credentials I only get the login page in return (e.g. not successful).

Login form:

```
<form method="post" action="/user/account/login/">
<div id=loginform>
<label class="field-title">Username </label><label class="txt-field"><input name="username" type="text" tabindex="1" /></label>
<label class="field-title">Password </label><label class="txt-field"><input name="password" type="password" tabindex="2"/></label>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var loginUrl = "https://example.org/user/account/login/";
var username = 'myuser';
    password = 'mypass';

var Request = unirest.post(loginUrl);

Request.auth({
  user: username,
  pass: password,
  sendImmediately: true
});

Request.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

and this:

```
Request.auth({
  username: username,
  password: password,
  sendImmediately: true
});
```

.. and this:

```
Request.send({
    username: username,
    password: password
});
```

but to no avail. I don't have to use Unirest, are there other easy libraries for logging in and using the login cookie for further requests?